# python sqlalchemy Multi-table association commit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Relationship like this:

```
a->b one->many
a->c one->many
b->c one->many
```

This is a example code:

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    b = relationship("A", backref="a")

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = "b"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("a.id"))
    c = relationship("C", backref="b")

class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = "c"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("a.id"))
    b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("b.id")) 

a = A()
a.b = [B(), B()]

session.add(a)
session.commit()
```

it's ok. but when i use like this:

```
a = A()
a.b = [B(), B()]
a.b.c = [C(), C()]
session.add(a)
session.commit()
```

it do not work. Please help me, i want foreignkey be automatically associated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a.b` is a vector according to your definition. You'd need to get a scalar via `first()` or `one()` (or similar, I haven't got the SQLA docs to hand right now) and assign to that object's `c` property, I believe.

Comment: thanks you for your answer，i try a.b[0].c = [C(), C()], then b_id is automatically associated, but a_id is not. Is there a better way to associate them at the same time?

Comment: I have not made it clear. I means table B has a_id, but table C has not, only b_id exist.

Comment: Well, this is actually a problem with your object graph. You have two routes from A to C: A -> C directly and A -> B -> C. If you populate your relationship via `a.b.c` it won't be populated via the other automatically. I would ditch the `a.id` FK in C as it's superfluous. You can always resolve via B.

Comment: You are right, it's my problem.Thanks again for your patience.